# WSO2 ESB Clustering with Governance Registry

Tags: registry, wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-esb

i m trying to build a cluster  made up on 3 WSO2 ESB:

1 ESB Manager node

2 ESB worker nodes

Till now i referenced to the official documentation at this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+WSO2+Products

But now i need to know how and if it's possible to build a cluster withouth an svn server for Deployment Synchronizer and sharing all the configuration just using the Governance Registry.

Is there an official guide? or just have i to reference to this tutorial i found out on the net:

http://emsooriyabandara.blogspot.it/2013/01/registry-based-deployment-synchronizer.html

Regards

Comment: Registry based Deployment synchronizer not recommended in production environments. Better to use svn based approach.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned tutorial is fine. G-Reg based deployment synchronizer is not recommended by WSO2. From Carbon 4.2.x onward it is deprecated. Because G-Reg stores artifact in database and with passage of time if number of artifacts increases than definitely the number of database calls will be increase. So, huge performance impact.

You can use G-Reg based synchronizer, if your service has less number of artifacts and the deployments are not frequent.